# In Ruby on Rails, what is an "asset"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### What's considered an "asset" in the Ruby on Rails universe?

Are *user generated files*, such as images uploaded by the user, considered **assets**?  Where should they be stored in the standard file structure of a Rails project?  Should they be kept clear of any asset related directories like:

- app/**assets**
- lib/**assets**
- public/**assets**

Relevant: [The Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `asset` is anything that browser loads after it gets the HTML page. Meaning javascript, css and any images. But as you pointed out there are two different image types in a rails project.

1) the images related to your css and layout design, those go under the `app/assets/images` 
2) the images that your users upload, those normally go into the `public/system` or `public/uploads` folder depending on what you use to receive the uploads

The `lib/assets` (or sometimes `vendor/assets`) is where you supposed to place js/css/images related to your front-end design and provided by third party libs. Say if you want to pull in some css or a js framework, that were you should place it.

And finally `public/assets` is where rails will *compile* your layout assets from the `app/assets` and `vendor/assets` folders when you run `rake assets:precompile` task for production.

To have it short, your design stuff goes to `app/assets`, and the user uploads go into `public/system`

Comment: Great answer!  The way you lay out the difference between an asset that's part of your app and one supplied by the user is something that should be in the Rails docs.

Answer (score 0):

User-uploaded files are not part of assets, and should definitely be kept clear of asset-related folders. You should put them somewhere in your `public` directory. I put mine in `public/uploads`, which is a common convention. And then you should ignore those files in git (or whatever VCS you're using).

Assets are basically: javascript, stylesheets, fonts, and images which are part of the site design itself, not part of the user-uploaded content.

Comment: I hadn't heard of `public/uploads` as a convention and that helps me out immensely. Thanks!